# How to prevent crashing from a invalid input in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, error-handling, int

I made a simple application to add 2 numbers together but when I add two letters together or a invalid sign it crashes the program. How do I create a message box showing something saying "*please put in a number*" when someone inserts a letter

Here's my code:

```
public partial class frmAdd : Form
{
    string first;
    string second;
    public frmAdd()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        first = txtNumber.Text;
    }

    private void btnSecond_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        second = txtNumber.Text;
    }

    private void btnResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(first);
        int b = Convert.ToInt32(second);
        int c = a + b;
        txtResult.Text = c.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this Code <br/>

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028673/c-sharp-numeric-only-textbox-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) instead:

```
private void btnResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a, b;
    if (int.TryParse(first, out a) && int.TryParse(second, out b))
    {
        int c = a + b;
        txtResult.Text = c.ToString();
    } 
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input!");
    }
}
```

Or perhaps a better method would be to trap the error when the user first inputs the data:

```
public partial class frmAdd : Form 
{ 
    int first;   // changed to int
    int second;

    private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out this.first))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input!");
        }
    }

    private void btnSecond_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out this.second))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input!");
        }
    }

    private void btnResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int c = first + second;
        txtResult.Text = c.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2705420 That's the [conditional-AND operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx). It will try to parse `first` and if it succeeds, will then try to parse `second`. If both succeed, it will execute the contents `if`-block; otherwise it will execute the `else`-block.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NumericUpDown` control instead of `TextBox` - it will not allow user to input invalid data.

Or you can add validation to `TextBox` value after user entered something. Add `ErrorProvider` to your form. And subscribe to `Validating` event of `txtNumber` textbox. This event will occur when textbox loses focus. If entered text is not an integer, then error will be shown near texbox, and your button will not be clicked:

```
private void txtNumber_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    int value;
    if (!Int32.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out value))
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtNumber, "Value is not an integer");
        return;
    }

    errorProvider1.SetError(txtNumber, "");
    first = value; // it's better to save integer value than text
}
```

Validation looks like:

[image]

Comment: what does NumericUpDown do?

Comment: @user2705420, a `NumericUpDown` is just another type of input control, just like a TextBox, but this control only lets you types in numbers (with or without decimals). The "Up Down" comes from the up and down buttons within the control.

Comment: Thanks, as you can see im pretty low level but does the .SetError create a messagebox or will it show in the txtNumber

Comment: @user2705420 it will show error icon and tooltip with error message, see sample screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bit of validation to check if you can create an `int` from the `string` value passed in.
`int.TryParse` is a simple way of doing this.

And for the `MessageBox` you can just use the `MessageBox` calss

Example:

```
private void btnResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    if (!int.TryParse(first, out a))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("first is not a number");
        return;
    }
    if (!int.TryParse(second, out b))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("second is not a number");
        return;
    }
    int c = a + b;
    txtResult.Text = c.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Convert.ToInt32(string), you might actually use Int32.tryParse(String, out int), as shown below:

```
int a, b;

a = Int32.tryParse(first, out a);
b = Int32.tryParse(second, out b);
```

If the conversion fails, the tryParse method will result in a zero. If it succeeds, it will give you the number which is to be found in the string.

Hope it helped you out, had to find this too in my first few days of C#.