# Validator in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a textbox that will only accpet numbers, so i have to make validator that accept only number except 0, what's the regular expression i should do, any help please, i have already try this :

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regValSummary" runat="server"
  ControlToValidate="txtSummary" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="[1-9]*"     
  ValidationGroup="grpLigneComande">
  *
 </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

any suggestion please !!

Comment: Your regularExpressionValidator will happen server side, is the problem you want client side validation or that the user can enter other characters than numbers from 1-9 and it passes validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Compare Validator instead of RegularExpressionValidator like

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ValueToCompare="0" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
ErrorMessage="Must enter positive integers" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Integer"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

i think a RegularExpressionValidator won't be able to help you. Try exploring MaskedTextBox. [C# Numeric Only TextBox Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028673/c-sharp-numeric-only-textbox-control)

Or if you're using Ajax Control Toolkit, try the FilteredTextBoxExtender, using a sample MobileNo textfield which will accept numbers except 0:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMobileNo" runat="server" CssClass="textBox" Width="200px" MaxLength="15" />
<ajax:FilteredTextBoxExtender runat="server" ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender4" TargetControlID="txtMobileNo" FilterMode="ValidChars" FilterType="Numbers, Custom" ValidChars="+-" InvalidChars="0" />
```