# Textbox with specific numbers

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a `TextBox` in windows form application in visual studio that contains only specific numbers. for example i want one textbox to be able to contain only numbers between `0` and `1`. If its any other value I want a message to appear that says wrong number. The app is in written in C#.

I have seen this example 
[C# Numeric Only TextBox Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028673/c-sharp-numeric-only-textbox-control)
but it is for numeric and i want specific numeric.

Edit:My mistake i wasn't clear enough. i tried the NumericUpDown but it doesn't work for all examples. In the second box i want to have values from 20 to 340 but only the .5 floating points between (20,20.5,21 etc) and if i use NumericUpDown, if the user inserts 22.6 the cell accepts it and i don't want that. That's why i ask if it's possible to control the value inserted with a Textbox or a MaskedTextBox and if it's eligible then for the user to be able to enter it the box. Hope i am clear enough now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any effort from the OP.

Comment: @PatrickHofman > Well, a number between 0 and 1 will most probably be a floating number, therefore quite hard to get a complete dropdown list...

Comment: @Bartdude: but a up down would suffice, right?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: With the current info givn by OP, it's impossible to say. If it was for Integers, your solution would be enough, if we're talking floating point numbers, we've got to know the limits do decimal digits, if there are steps and so on as you can always find a real number in between 2 others real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [`NumericUpDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can use it like this;

```
NumericUpDown control = new NumericUpDown();
control.Minimum = 0;
control.Maximum = 1;
control.DecimalPlaces = 2; // or something you want.
control.Increment = .01;   // step is .01
```

Comment: I hope the numbers aren't up to 10 decimal places, else getting to 0.8956485212 will take a lot of clicks :-)

Comment: @Bartdude: you can always type in it if you want to. Let's create a swipe gesture for it ;)

Comment: oh ok. My bad, I have a very limited knowledge of winforms controls from a developer point of view and I undrstand which type of control this is actually. I get your point now !

Comment: @PatrickHofman well this can do the job but what i don;t like is that when i type an incorrect value it just gives back a random value (eligible though). i want the user to not be able to press a button if it;s not correct.that why i wanted to use a textbox maybe with an event keypress and to control there if that number is eligible or not

Answer (score 0):

create user control inheriting TextBox and add an event for KeyPress as follows

```
public class MyTextBox:TextBox
{
    List<int> numberstobeallowed = Enumerable.Range(20, 340 - 20).ToList();
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        this.Leave += new EventHandler(MyTextBox_Leave);
    }

    void MyTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (numberstobeallowed.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(this.Text)))
            this.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

hope this helps